# Using special characters in Unified Remote

Tags: keyboard, android, remote

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and installed Unified Remote server.
Whatever keyboard method I try from my Android smartphone, only `,` and `-` special characters work on Ubuntu.

Why letters, digits and other keys work, but not majority of special characters?

Unified remote server has this information:

"Input Mode: uinput (X11 not available)"

Unified Remote server on Ubuntu: 3.10.0.2467 (49)

Unified Remote client on Android: 3.21.0

Comment: Apparently only available in the full version: https://www.unifiedremote.com/features#keyboard

Comment: I already own Unified Remote Full on Android phone

Comment: Which keyboard are you using? It says it works with third party keyboards like SwifKey and Swipe but doesn't mention others. However, other characters should work even without the premium version (as long as you don't need CTRL or ALT, etc.). Since you have the premium version, you might want to contact the developers and/or file a bug report. Also, do you use the US or UK keyboard layout or something else?

Comment: You meant keyboard remotes? If so, on Android app -> Remotes or Quick Switch Remotes, I've tried: Keyboard English Keyboard, Keyboard (Function), Numpad, Keyboard (German). I don't need special characters that are not usually printed on the real keyboard (the ones that are access via CTRL or ALT keys). I've contacted developers to try to solve the issue in parallel. Using latest versions of Unified Remote client and server. Any guesses that issue is on client side - Android or server side - Ubuntu? Is there a possibility that Ubuntu should be reconfigured to support it?

Comment: FYI: issue is identified by Unified Remote developers. This is the case for Ubuntu.